# function in codeIgniter help conflicting with another function

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpbb3

In codeIgniter I auto load the `url_helper.php`
In my site I also have a phpbb forum and so within codeigniter im trying to `include` a script from the forum.

The problem is, phpbb tries to declare a function `redirect()` but its already declared in the url_helper.php so i get the following error

> Cannot redeclare redirect() (previously declared in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\system\helpers\url_helper.php:531) in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\forum\includes\functions.php on line
>   2562

What can I do go go around this? Can I unset the function or remove the url_helper entirly in my controller function?

Comment: [This related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168805/codeigniterphpbb-function-redeclaration) might help.

Comment: umm excuse me but why the minus 1? This question is as relevant as it can be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got a work around. In the codeigniter's helper library, before declaring a function, it first checks if it has been declared before or not. So....

In my controller class's constructor method, I load all the phpbb files I need. this way it declares the phpbb redirection function and codeigniter goes "ohh there is already a redirect function" and so it doesn't declare the redirect function... Problem solved

Something like this:

```
class Register extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        /* START phpbb */
        .
        .
        .
        require_once('forum/common.php');
        require_once('forum/includes/functions_user.php');
        require_once('forum/includes/functions_module.php');
        /* END phpbb */        

        //Continue as normal
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        //Your stuff works as normal now
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Still a bit of a hack, but see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php

You could create your own url_helper, include the CI url_helper, and call after include:

rename_function('redirect', 'ci_redirect');